# LabVIEW Call Library Function yielding array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, labview

I need to interface C code to LabVIEW, and my C function needs to give back a two dimensional array of strings. I would rather not be forced to predetermine the size of the array in advance. So I want to know, what is the right data format to use (handle to array of C string pointers? Handle to array of string handles?), how to properly do the allocation, and whether it is better to use an array parameter or a return type. The dialog provided for Call Library Function Node only supports arrays of numeric types, so I'm a little bit lost on how to structure this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the [LabVIEW Code Interface Reference Manual](http://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/320539c) to figure this stuff out.

You are writing a C function that will return a 2D array of strings to LabVIEW. That means you need to be returning LabVIEW's data structure and using LabVIEW's memory allocator. Include "extcode.h" in your C file (ships with LabVIEW). Then create the following C code:

```
#include "extcode.h"

struct String2DArrayBlock {
    int32 dimensionSize1;
    int32 dimensionSize2;
    LStrHandle stringArray[1]; // Yes, this is intentional. Do not use LStrHandle* because that syntax changes the memory allocation. Old-school C code. LabVIEW's own C++ code has wrappers for managing this with more type safety. 
};

typedef String2DArrayBlock** String2DArrayHandle;

MgErr GenerateMyStrings(String2DArrayHandle *ptrToHandle) {
    if (!ptrToHandle)
        return mgArgErr; // Gotta pass a location for us to allocate.

    if (*ptrToHandle) {
        // This handle is already allocated. I'm not going to walk you through all the code needed to deallocate.
        return mgArgErr;
    }

    const int32 dimSize1 = ComputeHeight(); // This is your function... whereever your data is coming from.
    const int32 dimSize2 = ComputeWidth(); // Same here. 

    const int32 numberOfElements = dimSize1 * dimSize2;

    if (numberOfElements == 0) {
        return mgNoErr; // Done. NULL means empty array, and the handle is already NULL.
    }

    // DSNewHClr allocates the block and flood fills it with all zeros.
    *ptrToHandle = (String2DArrayHandle)DSNewHClr(sizeof(String2DArrayBlock) + ((numberOfElements - 1) * sizeof(LStrHandle))); // -1 because the sizeof block has 1 element. 
    if (!*ptrToHandle)
        return mFullErr; // Out of memory

    (**ptrToHandle)->dimensionSize1 = dimSize1;
    (**ptrToHandle)->dimensionSize2 = dimSize2;

    LStrHandle *current = (**ptrToHandle)->stringArray;
    for (int32 i = 0; i < numberOfElements; ++i, ++current) {
        std::string myCurrentString = GetMyCurrentString(i); // You write this however you look up the individual strings.
        if (myCurrentString.empty())
            continue; // NULL means empty string
        *current = (LStrHandle)DSNewHClr(sizeof(LStr)); // Allocates a zero-length LStrHandle.
        if (!*current)
            return mFullErr; // The array will be partially filled, but it is in a safe state for early return.
        MgErr err = LStrPrintf(*current, (CStr)"%s", myCurrentString.c_str());
        if (err)
            return err; // The array will be partially filled, but it is in a safe state for early return.
    }

    return mgNoErr;
}
```

Compile your code against the LabVIEW run-time engine (lvrt.dll).

In your G code, drop a Call Library Node, add a parameter that is "Adapt to type" and "Pointers to Handles", and wire it with an empty 2D array. And you're done.

Comment: The memory layout for strings and arrays hasn't changed since LabVIEW 1.0 back in 1986, which is why screenshots in that PDF file are taken from the original Macintosh.

Comment: And if you need any further support on the PDF, just dial into NI's BBS or fax their faxback service!